# How to show Chinese or Japanese on Debian linux console?

Tags: linux, utf-8, console, debian, locale

My linux console does not show utf-8 Chinese or Japanese, but the locale setting seems correct.

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.4 (jessie)
Release:        8.4
Codename:       jessie

$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by adding following lines to .screenrc setting file

```
defutf8 on
defencoding utf8
encoding UTF-8 UTF-8
```